# Why does a copied file have a different size?

Tags: files, transfer

When I copy files between two hard drives on the same Ubuntu 14.04 system, using the `du -s` command, I get different values. For an 11.3 GB files the original is 11015704 and the new is 11015628. The original has ext4 and it was transfered to an NTFS file system.

Why are the file sizes different?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/300409/is-ext4-more-expensive-than-ntfs

Answer (score 6):

(Most useful) file systems store files in blocks of (more or less) fixed size. That means a typical file will occupy more space than its logical size because there are some unused bytes left over in one of its file system blocks. The blocks size can vary by file system type and/or can be configured during file system creation which means that the disk usage of the same file on one file system may differ on another.

By default `du` reports the actual space that files occupy on the drive (i. e. the number of occupied blocks multiplied by the block size).

If you want `du` to report the (collective) logical file sizes you need to use the `--apparent-size` option (or `-b` which implies `--apparent-size`).

From the [`du(1)` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/du.1.html):

> `--apparent-size` – print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,  and the like

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!